# Is overloading of main method with string []args and varargs possible??if not then why?

Tags: java, overloading

Is overloading of main method with string []args and varargs possible??if not then why??i tried following code which gave compilation error.please help .i m new to java.

```
public class obj1 {

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        System.out.println("main method varargs");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main method string arrays");
    }
}
```

Comment: Variadic arguments (`...`) are really just syntactic sugar for an array argument. As such, you are trying to define two methods with the same signature.

Comment: Also here explained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301563/difference-fnstring-args-vs-fnstring-args

Comment: @AndyTurner you should write that as an answer, not a comment :)

Comment: @sotix T.J.Crowder wrote a better answer :)

Comment: I'd be surprised if this weren't a duplicate (though oddly I haven't found one yet), but it certainly *isn't* a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759315/can-we-overload-the-main-method-in-java. RichardK's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301563/difference-fnstring-args-vs-fnstring-args is much closer but doesn't address trying to have both in the same class.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375823/method-overloading-with-argument-vararg-of-object-class-and-array-of-object-clas

Comment: @Tunaki: Excellent.

Answer (score 5):

In Java, both of those methods are really `public static void main(String[] args)` (fundamentally). That's why it won't compile; you can't have a class with two `public static void main(String[])` methods.

Java added variadic arguments by having the function compiled as accepting an array, and then by making calls to the function automatically wrap the variadic arguments in an array.

That is, if we have

```
void foo(String... args)
```

called with

```
foo("one", "two", "three");
```

what the compiler actually creates is

```
void foo(String[] args)
```

called with

```
foo(new String[] { "one", "two", "three"})
```

(The compiler marks the method in the class file so that it knows later that the array at the end is variadic, but the code it creates is for a method accepting an array.)

This is mostly covered by [JLS§8.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-FormalParameterList):

> The last formal parameter of a method or constructor is special: it may be a *variable arity parameter*, indicated by an ellipsis following the type.
>
> ...
>
> The declared type of a formal parameter depends on whether it is a variable arity parameter:
>
> - If the formal parameter is not a variable arity parameter, then the declared type is denoted by *UnannType* if no bracket pairs appear in UnannType and VariableDeclaratorId, and specified by §10.2 otherwise.
> - If the formal parameter is a variable arity parameter, then the declared type is specified by §10.2. (Note that "mixed notation" is not permitted for variable arity parameters.)

...where [§10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2) is talking about arrays.

In fact, it's perfectly valid to call a `foo(String...)` method with an array instead of discrete arguments. Example, suppose we have:

```
private static void foo(String... args) {
    for (String s : args) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

we can call that either like this:

```
foo("one", "two", "three");
```

or like this

```
foo(new String[] { "four", "five", "six"});
```

Both are perfectly valid; example: http://ideone.com/a1Ku37